# Travi-ci.com Can Read Env Variables, But travs-ci.com Doesn't

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, travis-ci, dotenv

I have a node.js project ([repo here](https://github.com/JimLynchCodes/Super-Scraper/blob/master/README.md)) that I've been running for a while on [travis-ci.org](https://travis-ci.org), but it always fails on [travis-ci.com](https://travis-ci.com/github/JimLynchCodes/Super-Scraper)...

I have entered the environment variables like so:

[image]

The node.js application uses the dotenv library and reads the variable `MONGO_URI`.

The strange thing is that I run EXACTLY the same code with EXACTLY the same environment variables, but I get completely different results depending if I run it on the "dot com" travis-ci site or the "dot org" site...

It always runs fine on the "org" travis-ci, but it always come in an "undefined" in the "com" travis-ci site.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, had a tough time debugging this, but it seems that everything works when I wrap the values in single quotes.